# Binding to the same array in a different section

Tags: angularjs

I have the following plnkr (although it doesn't display the data):
http://plnkr.co/edit/7jAzOftz9Yq6hXNts9kf?p=preview

I have 2 div sections:

```
<div ng-controller="AddChoreController as chores">

<div class="row clearfix" ng-controller="AddChoreController as chores">
```

What I'm trying to do is to build an array in 1 section and then reuse the array in a different section.  I get that I'm just instantiating the same controller, my question is how when I update the choreList.chores array can I show it in the second div section?

Comment: You'd need to have them share this array object, and it's probably best done with a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a service to share across your app / controllers. I included a snippet below to demonstrate how you might do this.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController1', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.myService = myService;
});

app.controller('myController2', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.myService = myService;
});

app.service('myService', function() {
  this.arr = [];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='myController1'>
    myController1 #1
    <input ng-model="myService.arr"/>
    {{ myService.arr }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='myController1'>
    myController1 #2
    <input ng-model="myService.arr"/>
    {{ myService.arr }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='myController2'>
    myController2
    <input ng-model="myService.arr"/>
    {{ myService.arr }}
  </div>
<div>
```